# why wont the template i am calling show up when i set my form to "crispy"

Tags: django

i have a django project with a login page i have called register.html i have created a directory in my project called users and keeping with django another directory named users and a sub-directory template->users->register:

```
my_project/
├── my_project/
│   ├── ...
│
├── users/
│   ├── templates/
│   │   ├── users/
│   │   │   ├── register.html
│
└── ...
```

the code for the page is as follow:

```html
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="Welcome to our text messaging campaigning website">
    <title>R&D Texting</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>hi</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% comment %} Do not remove the csrf token! {% endcomment %}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class = "form-group">
                <legend class ="border-bottom mb-4">Join today</legend>
                {{form|crispy}}
                


            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign up</button>

            </div>

        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
          <small class="text-muted">
            Already have an account?<a class ="ml-2" href="#">Sign in</a>"

          </small>  
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

when i run this code(with the proper urls and paths etc) i get a 404 page saying it cant find the template
when i remove the "|crispy" everything runs fine.
my rendering request form views etc seem to be find however the crispy template cant be found(i have made sure to isntall the proper packages).

any suggestions on how to fix this would be great i will also add the error page:

```
bootstrap4/uni_form.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/
Django Version: 4.2.4
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
bootstrap4/uni_form.html
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py, line 84, in reraise
Raised during:  users.views.register
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.11.3
Python Path:    
['/Users/davidmarks/django_project',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python311.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 28 Aug 2023 18:02:47 +0000
```